# How to specify a default value for an array of maps with Params for Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following problem with my Phoenix app: I've been using [params](https://github.com/vic/params) for a while now and it works nicely.

```
defparams update_config %{
    id!: :integer,
    show_images: [field: :boolean, default: false],
    attachment_filename: [field: :string, default: nil]
}
```

The controller then does

```
changeset = update_config(params)

case changeset.valid? do
    true ->
        params = Params.to_map(changeset)
```

But now I want to add another parameter `recipients`:

```
defparams update_config %{
    id!: :integer,
    name: :string,
    show_images: [field: :boolean, default: false],
    attachment_filename: [field: :string, default: nil],
    recipients: [
        %{
            mail!: :string
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, recipients is an array of maps. Notice that this parameter has no default value! When I do a request and send an empty array for recipients, then `Params.to_map` will delete it completely.

I think, this is working as expected - see this quote from the docs:

> Note that `Params.data` and `Params.to_map` have different behaviour: `data` returns a struct which will include all valid params. `to_map` returns a map that only includes the submitted keys and keys with default values.

But I don't want my recipients param to disappear (even if it's an empty array). I tried several ways to specify a default value, but nothing worked. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Does `Params.data` return `recipients: []` for this case?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes it does.

Comment: So, you could do `Params.data(...) |> Map.from_struct` and get exactly what you want?

Comment: I just tested your suggestion: Basically this approach works, but then my map contains additional keys `__meta__` and `_id`. I know, they can be deleted easily... but it feels a little bit hacky though.